# What is this cipher/hash?

Tags: hash, cryptography, encryption

Please refer to this JsFiddle where I have the data separated by the appropriated columns:

http://jsfiddle.net/hsZvq/

Good Demo (For those who don't want to click the link):

```
Unique ID   Generated Code                    Part 1             Part 2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
877023281   9F044F5BCF2D97B2                  9F044F5BCF2D97B2 
790200492   3B9BD10FBDB90D7F613313A492ACC67B  3B9BD10FBDB90D7F   613313A492ACC67B
```

The **Generated Code** is somehow generated /derived for the **Unique ID**. At first I think it was a 256-bit hash because all the codes were a set length, but some of the ID's actually only have 128-bit so that leads me to believe its a combination hash.

If you split up each 128-bit part of the code you will notice that the 2nd part repeats itself a lot. It seems to be based on something that is obviously repeating.

`note:`
Unique ID may refer to the numerical value given or possibly the numerical value with an R infront. For example the above Generated Code may be based on `877023281` or `R877023281`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the function?

It would be helpful to generate a bunch of input/output pairs where the inputs are more related to each other.  For example, inputs that differ by only one bit: 0,1,2,4,8,16,.... and 1,3,5,9,17,..

Even if the function is close to trivial, the small number of samples you have presented doesn't offer much fodder for analysis.

Of course, if you have the code, you could try reverse-engineering the code instead of its numerical output.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the function. Is there any general techniques / analysis software that could be used on the limited data set?

Comment: Are those all your samples of input/output pairs, or do you have lots more?  Are you willing to write code or are you hoping for something turn-key?

Comment: I can write code, those all the pairs I have at the moment. I can get more in due-time.